# A newbie question about the use of the FourierSeries functions

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, fourier-analysis

Although I have had no previous experience with the Mathematica Fourier Series functions ( or package ), I am writing a tutorial on Fourier Analysis and Transformations in a Mathematica Notebook, using a standard ( not high-end ) Windows PC which runs Mathematica 11.3 usually with excellent performance ( how relative and unspecific that may sound ).

I started with an example using the following code.

```
 ClearAll[f, g, h];
 f[x_] := Piecewise[{{3, 0 < x < 1}, {-3, 1 < x < 2}}]
 g[x_] := f[Mod[x, 2]]
 h[x_] = FourierSeries[g[x], x, 30];
 Show[
  Plot[g[x], {x, -1, 3}, Filling -> Axis],
  Plot[h[x], {x, -1, 3}],
  PlotRange -> {-4, 4}
 ]
```

This code ran as expected, with the following output.

[image]

Then, I changed the code to:

```
 ClearAll[f, g, h, k];
 f[x_] := Piecewise[{{3, 0 < x < 1}, {-3, 1 < x < 2}}]
 g[x_] := f[Mod[x, 2]]
 h[x_] = FourierSeries[g[x], x, 30];
 k[x_] = FourierTrigSeries[g[x], x, 30];
 Show[
  Plot[g[x], {x, -1, 3}, Filling -> Axis],
  Plot[h[x], {x, -1, 3}],
  Plot[k[x], {x, -1, 3}],
  PlotRange -> {-4, 4}
 ]
```

( Note the addition of k(x) with the purpose to compare FourierSeries and FourierTrigSeries ).

Performance degraded considerably... I checked the Windows 10 Performance Monitor : memory consumption was as high as I have ever seen.

[image]

My point is that running this code took ( probably >> 10 times ) the time it took to run the first batch of code.

The output... was exactly the same ( which was to be expected ).

[image]

If you forgive my lack of experience with the FourierSeries type of functions I have the following questions:

- Is the specification of my code such that the execution is not optimal?
- Why is there such a difference in run-time between FourierSeries and FourierTrigSeries?
- Do you have any other tips, advice or links for newbie users of the FourierSeries functions?

Comment: Minor commnet, your `f` is `3 SquareWave[x/2]`.

Comment: New to me, thanks.

Comment: The only possible explanation I can see for this is a flaw in Mathematica's implementation of `FourierTrigSeries`

Comment: I absolutely second what mikado said. Best to tell Wolfram Support about the issue.

Comment: Using SquareWave things speeded up though. I'll test it in Mma 12 which I'll install today.